# How to check result of Resource Removal Operation for Azure Resource

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, log-analysis

Using Resource Management API I can remove Azure resource (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources#Resources_DeleteById). This API returns 202 that removal is accepted - the resource is not removed right away though. The response header in my case contains "x-ms-request-id" value. How can I use it to get the status of this operation? Did the operation succeed? In my case I am removing the Log Analytics Solution resource.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I have checked this issue. I assumed that azure would take some time to handle your request, you could leverage  [Azure resource Get By Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources#Resources_GetById) to check your azure resource as follows:

[image]

For a simple way, you could leverage [resources.azure.com](https://resources.azure.com), choose your resource and check the details. I removed my Log Analytics, then I could retrieve the following result:

[image]

**UPDATE**

According to your latest comment, I have checked the REST API again and both tested the operations on ASM and ARM, you could refer to them as follows:

- For classic Azure Services (ASM)

You could use [Get Operation Status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460783.aspx) with [authentication using a management certificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx) to check the operation status.

- For ARM

You could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-async-operations) about tracking asynchronous Azure operations. You could use the header values returned by the asynchronous REST operations, then request the related URL with [authentication using Azure Active Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx) to determine the status of your operation.

Based on your azure service, you need to use the ARM approach.

Comment: Bruce, so your suggestion is to periodically get resource by using "Get by Id" after removal and wait for 404? If I receive 404 - is it safe to assume that the resource is completely removed? The experience in azure portal is next: I click delete resource button, and notification appears in the right upper corner after the resource is completely removed.  I thought that there might be an actual REST API to check status of  remove operation (x-ms-request-id must be the operation ID). Azure portal is able report success/failure of remove operation. With "Get by Id" I would not know why it failed

Comment: Bruce, this was very informative update, but still I am unable to get the operation status. I am trying to remove the Log Analytics Solution resource (it contains searches, schedules, actions, views). URL: "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions/AMP%20Web[xxxx]?api-version=2015-11-01-preview". I receive 200 back and this payload: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-ms-request-id: 438xxxx
x-ms-correlation-request-id: 9273fxxx
x-ms-routing-request-id: WESxxx. But clearly, it doesn't remove all the resources at the same time.

Comment: even though I am removing the resource using ARM api, it doesn't provide me usual Azure-AsyncOperation headers.

Comment: Based on your description, I assumed that you could try to add your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-log-analytics) for further support.